# Bayesian updating on two variables

Tags: bayesian, prior

Consider a variable $x$ with prior distribution $f(x)$ over the support $X$. Suppose we observe a signal $s$. Then, by using the likelihood $L(s|x)$ of observing this signal for a given $x$, I know that we can update our prior as follows.

$f'(x) = \dfrac{L(s|x)f(x)}{\int\limits_{x\in X} L(s|x')f(x')dx'}$

However, I am having trouble doing the same when the signal depends on two independent variables $x$ and $y$ with prior distributions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$. We now have a similar likelihood of observing a signal $s$ for a given $x$ and $y$ given by $L(s|x,y)$. Now, how do we simultaneously update $f(x)$ and $g(y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is very similar to the univariate case:
$$
f'(x, y) = \dfrac{L(s|x, y)f(x)f(y)}{\int\limits_{x\in X} \int\limits_{y\in Y} L(s|x', y')f(x')f(y') dx' dy'}
$$
Even though $x$ and $y$ are a-priori independent, they will not generally be independent in the posterior/new prior.